# How do I take a bunch of 2d matrices from .dat files and put them into one big 3d matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to combine all these 2d matrices I have in .dat files into a single 3d matrix.

So what I've done so far is this:

```
for (i=1:40) //There are 40 of these files
fileName = ['Solutionm1.dat/Solution' num2str(i-1) '.dat'] //This line sets a file name
f=fopen(fileName,'r') //I'm just opening the file now
A{i}=fread(f,'double') //Now I'm converting the binary file into a matlab matrix
B{i}=reshape(A{i},41,21) //Now I'm putting it into the shape that I want (I don't know of a better way to read binary files)
fclose all
end
```

Ultimately, I want to take the L2 norm of this 3d matrix by using `norm((insert 3d matrix here),2)`

The problem I'm having is that I just don't know how to combine all the matrices I just made into one big 3D matrix.

**Solution**

Use

```
T(:,:,i)=B{i}
```

or use

```
T=cat(3,B{:})
```

**Continued problem**

This doesn't work now:

```
norm(T,2) //Should compute the L2 norm of my 3D matrix, right?
```

This might be out of the scope of this question though...

From what I've learned, I think norm has to be used on a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have B, run:

```
matrix3d = zeros(41,21,40);
for i=1:40
    matrix3d(:, :, i)=B{i};
end
```

You can also include `matrix3d(:, :, i)=B{i};` in your loop, and call `matrix3d = zeros(41,21,40);` before entering the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer on the top of my head, and need to go to meeting right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer!

```
T=Cat(3,B{:}) //Combines all matrices into one single 3D matrix
```

Comment: Oh nice! But might be more proper to fill the 3D directly in the loop without having to create a temporary variable B.