# Combine 2D matrices to form 3D one in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have 3 `20x2 double` arrays `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to combine them in one 3d array `D` so that `D(:,:,1)` will return `A`, `D(:,:,2)` will return `B` and `D(:,:,3)` will return `C`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I take a bunch of 2d matrices from .dat files and put them into one big 3d matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600582/how-do-i-take-a-bunch-of-2d-matrices-from-dat-files-and-put-them-into-one-big-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`cat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to concatenate along the third dimension might be the elegant way -

```
D = cat(3,A,B,C)
```

Here, the first input argument `3` specifies the dimension along which the concatenation is to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
A = 1*ones(20,2);
B = 2*ones(20,2);
C = 3*ones(20,2);

D = zeros(20,2,3);  % Preallocate the D Matrix
D(:,:,1) = A;       
D(:,:,2) = B;
D(:,:,3) = C;

D(1,1,1)  % prints 1
D(1,1,2)  % prints 2
D(1,1,3)  % prints 3
```